# Vim slow to open buffers, but not specifically in any sourcing plugin step

Tags: startup, performance, debugging

I'm using Vim primarily for rails projects, and have found a fairly significant difference in the start up time between a couple of my projects.

Here's one project's startuptime log, while opening a single .rb file:

```
185.767  002.679  002.679: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/ruby.vim          
190.811  004.781  004.781: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-rails/autoload/rails.vim
478.080  000.275  000.275: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions.vim
478.257  000.061  000.061: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/quickfix.vim
478.484  000.156  000.156: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline.vim
478.645  000.035  000.035: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/netrw.vim
478.782  000.024  000.024: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/term.vim
478.944  000.059  000.059: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/ctrlp.vim
479.145  000.069  000.069: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/hunks.vim
479.471  000.120  000.120: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/whitespace.vim
479.853  000.054  000.054: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/po.vim
480.050  000.089  000.089: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/wordcount.vim
480.242  000.024  000.024: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/keymap.vim
482.185  000.073  000.073: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/section.vim
482.524  000.188  000.188: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/highlighter.vim
484.883  000.101  000.101: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes.vim
486.300  001.637  001.536: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/gruvbox/autoload/airline/themes/gruvbox.vim
504.566  000.141  000.141: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/builder.vim
504.970  000.089  000.089: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/default.vim
576.879  389.599: opening buffers                                                 
577.160  000.126  000.126: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/autoload/ctrlp/utils.vimode
```

Note the big jump in clock after vim-rails, but unless I'm being dumb the self+sourced & self times are in ms right? So the clock appears to jump but without a corresponding 300ms time. Then, further down, 'opening buffers' appears to maybe account for that 300ms?

The other project is far, far worse - again, opening a single .rb file:

```
181.187  004.675  004.675: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-rails/autoload/rails.vim
4782.456  000.270  000.270: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions.vim
4782.607  000.053  000.053: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/quickfix.vim
4782.829  000.148  000.148: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline.vim
4782.985  000.035  000.035: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/netrw.vim
4783.113  000.024  000.024: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/term.vim
4783.280  000.059  000.059: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/ctrlp.vim
4783.479  000.070  000.070: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/hunks.vim
4783.797  000.114  000.114: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/whitespace.vim
4784.180  000.056  000.056: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/po.vim
4784.399  000.095  000.095: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/wordcount.vim
4784.598  000.026  000.026: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/keymap.vim
4786.604  000.072  000.072: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/section.vim
4786.961  000.204  000.204: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/highlighter.vim
4789.168  000.047  000.047: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes.vim
4790.483  001.470  001.423: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/gruvbox/autoload/airline/themes/gruvbox.vim
4809.004  000.138  000.138: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/builder.vim
4809.359  000.078  000.078: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/default.vim
4867.585  4686.103: opening buffers                                               
4867.862  000.126  000.126: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/autoload/ctrlp/utils.vim
```

same deal - the elapsed times don't seem to match the clock time. Looking at what's going on with the clock time it seems like vim-rails could be the culprit, but disabling it doesn't do the job, the apparent 5s jump is now at 'opening buffers':

```
177.576  000.045  000.045: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes.vim
178.888  001.464  001.419: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/gruvbox/autoload/airline/themes/gruvbox.vim
202.604  000.145  000.145: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/builder.vim
202.975  000.074  000.074: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/default.vim
5496.540  5327.812: opening buffers
```

vim -u NONE on the same files loads blazing fast, with no particular difference between the projects, as you'd expect.

I am using the following plugins:

```
ctrlp.vim/                 gruvbox/                  vim-bundler/        vim-pug/       vim-vue/
DeleteTrailingWhitespace/  ShowTrailingWhitespace~/  vim-coffee-script/  vim-rails/
delimitMate/               typescript-vim/           vim-endwise/        vim-slim/
emmet-vim/                 vim-airline/              vim-indent-guides/  vim-surround/
```

with Pathogen.

What's the next step in debugging this?

Comment: Please provide more information: Are you reloading buffers? (e.g. from a session or loading several buffers from the commandline)? Is accessing those buffers/files slow on your filesystem (e.g. NFS/network share or similar)? Could it be a anti-virus scanner intercepting loading the buffers? What other plugins are you using?

Comment: I've updated the original question. In all cases I'm opening a single buffer from the command line. Opening the same buffers with `-u NONE` is lightning fast. No AV. Have added a paste of my bundle directory.

Comment: Next step would be debug if a plugin or your personal .vimrc makes it slow. See the [faq](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the startup log wasn't actually very helpful here. There wasn't really any indication in the log that this was the culprit, but it turns out it was vim-bundler.

I actually didn't even paste the line for it, because its timestamps seemed so inconsequential, but:

```
 20 048.261  001.317  001.317: sourcing /home/thomas/.vim/bundle/vim-bundler/plugin/bundler.vim
```

I had this plugin at `48abb77`. upgrading to `a996611` has dramatically sped up my startup time in all rails projects.

My approach for figuring this out was just to start with a fresh `.vim/bundle` and reintroduce each plugin one at a time.